# What prevents Coq from performing a trivial rewrite?

Tags: coq

After `clear`ing all superfluous hypotheses, I have the following goal in Coq:

```
1 focused subgoals (unfocused: 1-1-1-0-0)
, subgoal 1 (ID 14043)

  in_contents : list byte
  H0 : Zlength in_contents = 1
  ============================
   0 <= 0 < Zlength in_contents
```

And, for context:

```
Print byte.
byte = {b : Z | 0 <= b < 256}
     : Set
```

However, `rewrite H0` gives:

> Error: Found no subterm matching "Zlength in_contents" in the current
>   goal.

However, I can do this ridiculous proof:

```
split; try omega.
change ((1-1) < Zlength in_contents); rewrite <- H0; omega.
```

I'm sure that I must be missing something fundamental here.

(Even more oddly, this works fine:)

```
Example what : forall (in_contents:list byte), Zlength in_contents = 1 -> 0 <= 0 < Zlength in_contents.
Proof.
  intros in_contents H0.
  rewrite H0.
  omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: Can you make a self-contained example? See "[mcve]". Also, what version of Coq are you using?

Comment: Can you run `Set Printing All.` and check that the expressions on your goal and your `H0` hypothesis really match?

Comment: I only hit this issue deep in a proof, and the file pulls in significant amounts of libraries from [VST](http://vst.cs.princeton.edu/). That's why I do not have a self-contained chunk to show, I'm afraid. (I tried to make a self-contained chunk but it works fine.) It's coq 8.4pl6.

Comment: `Set Printing All.` was what I needed to know, thank you! I had two definitions of `byte` and that was why it didn't match up.

Answer (score 3):

as others have mentioned, it is likely that the rewrite is obstructed by some hidden terms in your goal or hypotheses. There are two common sources for this kind of problems:

### Coercions:

Coercions (automatic type castings) are hidden by default by the Coq pretty printer. An example illustrating the issue is:

```
Section CRew.
Variable (A B : Type) (f : A -> B).

Coercion f : A >-> B.

Variable (x y : A).
Hypothesis H : @eq B x y.

Print H.

Lemma L1 : x = y.
(* rewrite H. fail *) Abort.

Set Printing Coercions.
Print H. (* H : f x = f y *)

End CRew.
```

In this case, H is really specifying an equality between `f x` and `f
y` but it is shown as `x = y`.

### Implicit Arguments

Another common source of confusion is the implicit arguments feature. Again, have a look at this code.

```
Section IARew.

Definition U := fun (_ : nat) => nat.
Variable (f : forall x, U x -> B).
Arguments f [x] y.

Hypothesis H : eq (@f 1 2) (@f 2 3).
Print H.

Lemma L2 : (@f 2 2) = (@f 2 3).
(* rewrite H. Fail. *) Abort.

Set Printing Implicit.
Print H.

End IARew.
```

Here, `@f 1 2` and `@f 2 2` are shown as `f 2`, leading to a confusion.

I hope it helps, you can run the examples at:
https://x80.org/collacoq/eqosecuzar.coq

Comment: By the way, the link doesn't work in Safari (version 9.1), but works all right in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the report, indeed jsCoq uses some EC2015 features that Safari is lagging behind; we'd be happy to implement a transpiling target.

Comment: Although `Set Printing All.` showed me the error of my code, I'd just like to thank you for the enlightening and well written answer.